# Optimise the sql query to remove N+1 problem in Ruby on Rails and Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

There are 2 models Buyer and BuyerOrder with 1 to many relationship.

```
class Buyer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many buyer_orders
end

class BuyerOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to buyer
end
```

I need to fetch total buyer_orders count and buyer name with group by buyer_id.
I can required data by below query.
`Buyer.all.map{|buyer| {buyer.id => {buyer_name: buyer.name, total: buyer.buyer_orders.count}}}`
Result of this query is:

```
[{1=>{:buyer_name=>"Buyer 1", :total=>58}},
 {2=>{:buyer_name=>"Buyer 2", :total=>10}},
 {3=>{:buyer_name=>"Buyer 3", :total=>4}}]
```

But this query has N+1 problem. How can optimise the query to remove N+1 problem?
My Rails version is 6.0.3.2 and Mysql version is 8.0.33

Can someone please help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `includes` method, to load association in query result, also use `size`, instead of `count`, `size` check if the association is already loaded before making a call to the database.

```rb
Buyer.all.includes(:buyer_orders).map{ |buyer| { buyer.id => { buyer_name: buyer.name, total: buyer.buyer_orders.size }}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
count query still executing multiple times.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try using `size` instead of `count`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `BuyerOrder` as a starting point instead of the `Buyer` because from the `BuyerOrder` you can already group them by the `buyer_id` attribute.

The following query will go 2 times to the database, no matter how much `Buyers` or `BuyerOrders` you have:

```rb
BuyerOrder.group(:buyer).count.map { |buyer| { buyer[0].id => { buyer_name: buyer[0].buyer_name, total: buyer[1]} } }
```

This will produce the result that you want without the N+1 problem.